# The Checker Framework seems to be ignoring -AskipUses argument

Tags: java, maven, checker-framework

I've started to annotate my program, writing the nullness annotations. Following the guidelines, I've annotated one of my classes and marked it as `@AnnotatedFor({"nullness"})`. The program is being compiled under the Java 7 platform, using Oracle JDK 1.7.u21 (can not switch to JDK 8 due to some technical limitations).
The class uses a bunch of unnanotated third-party (Google Guava) and JDK library methods, so I include the option `-AskipUses=...` along with the `-AuseSafeDefaultsForUnnanotatedSourceCode` in the Maven compiler plugin arguments  as follows:

```
<properties>
    <project.checker.annotatedJdk>${org.checkerframework:jdk7:jar}</project.checker.annotatedJdk>
    <project.checker.typeAnnotationsJavac>${org.checkerframework:compiler:jar}</project.checker.typeAnnotationsJavac>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessor>org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker</annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xbootclasspath/p:${project.checker.annotatedJdk}</arg>
                    <arg>-J-Xbootclasspath/p:${project.checker.typeAnnotationsJavac}</arg>
                    <arg>-AuseSafeDefaultsForUnannotatedSourceCode</arg>
                    <arg>-AskipUses=com\.google\.common\.|java\.math</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The source code of the class:

```
package pkg;

import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import com.google.common.base.*;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;
import org.checkerframework.framework.qual.AnnotatedFor;

@AnnotatedFor({"nullness"})
public class Indicator implements Comparable<Indicator> {

    private static final BigDecimal DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
    private static final Ordering<Indicator> ORDERING;

    public static enum IndicatorComparator implements Comparator<Indicator> {

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public final int compare(Indicator left, Indicator right) {

            /* nulls-last */
            if (left.sortOrder != null && right.sortOrder != null) {
                return left.sortOrder.compareTo(right.sortOrder);
            } else if (left.sortOrder != null && right.sortOrder == null) {
                return -1;
            } else if (left.sortOrder == null && right.sortOrder != null) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }

        }
    }

    static {
        DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0);
        ORDERING = Ordering.from(IndicatorComparator.INSTANCE).nullsLast();
    }

    private final int id;
    private @Nullable String code;
    private @Nullable BigDecimal sortOrder;
    private boolean isGroup;

    private Indicator(Builder builder) {
        id = builder.id;
        code = builder.code;
        sortOrder = builder.sortOrder;
        isGroup = builder.isGroup;
    }

    /* equals and hashcode are not overriden by purpose -- the default version will do */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Indicator other) {
        return ORDERING.compare(this, other);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("id", id)
                .add("code", code)
                .add("sortOrder", sortOrder)
                .add("isGroup", isGroup)
                .toString();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Optional<String> getCode() {
        return Optional.fromNullable(code);
    }

    public Optional<BigDecimal> getSortOrder() {
        return Optional.fromNullable(sortOrder);
    }

    public boolean isGroup() {
        return isGroup;
    }

    public void setCode(@Nullable String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setSortOrder(@Nullable BigDecimal sortOrder) {
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public void setGroup(boolean group) {
        this.isGroup = group;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private int id;
        private @Nullable String code;
        private @Nullable BigDecimal sortOrder;
        private boolean isGroup;

        public Builder() {
            sortOrder = DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
        }

        public Builder id(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder code(@Nullable String code) {
            this.code = code;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder sortOrder(@Nullable BigDecimal sortOrder) {
            this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder isGroup(boolean isGroup) {
            this.isGroup = isGroup;
            return this;
        }

        public Indicator build() {
            return new Indicator(this);
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the project, the Checker seems to be ignoring the 'skip' options, as I'm ended up with errors like

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
pkg/Indicator.java:[38,48] error:     [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
found   : @UnknownKeyFor double

required: @KeyForBottom double
```

leading us to the line 38:

```
DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0);
```

or 39:

```
pkg/Indicator.java:[39,52] error:     [argument.type.incompatible] incompatible types in argument.
found   : IndicatorComparator

required: Comparator<Indicator>
```

or 38 again:

```
pkg/Indicator.java:[38,47] error:     [assignment.type.incompatible] incompatible types in assignment.
found   : @UnknownInitialization @Nullable BigDecimal

required: @Initialized @NonNull BigDecimal
```

and so on -- the log is overflowed with various checker errors, though I thought I got rid of them by using the `-AskipUses=` option.

Am I doing something wrong?

UPD 07.12.2015: attached the full source code of the class.
UPD 14.12.2015: updated the source code, so it's much easier to reproduce the case now.

Comment: Can you give a complete, reproducible test case? Your source code snippet isn't compilable, and it doesn't contain 55 lines though your error messages refer to line 55. This makes it hard to get to the root of the problem. It would also help for you to determine whether the checker works from the command line or not -- that will indicate whether the problem is with the checker itself or with the Maven integration. Other tips for reporting bugs appear at http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#reporting-bugs . Then, hopefully someone can help you.

Comment: @mernst
I have not included the full source code for the sake of brevity, as I've also described what's on the line 55 (not on 58 though, my bad). But nonetheless I'll follow your advice and update the question tomorrow as I'll get to the workplace.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because it has mismatched curly braces.  It's also over 350 lines long.  Can you provide a minimal working example?  Thanks!

Comment: @mernst
I've shortened the source code (didn't think that someone would actually try to reproduce the issue) and actually tried to build it in a standalone project. The errors are the same. If I comment the line "<arg>-AuseSafeDefaultsForUnannotatedSourceCode</arg>" in the project's pom.xml, the compilation process seems to be fine (though I'm not sure the same applies to the type checking), but with this option turned on I get the errors above and -AskipUses doesn't really help.